# Logstash output to ES gives me error code '400'

Tags: docker, logging, twitter, logstash, elastic-stack

i am creating an ELK stack to fetch tweet and analyse them. When, i start my elk stack i got this error message from Logstash

```
Failed to install template {:message=>"Got response code '400' contacting Elasticsearch at URL 'http://elasticsearch:9200/_index_template/twitter'", :exception=>LogStash::Outputs::ElasticSearch::HttpClient::Pool::BadResponseCodeError, :backtrace=>["/usr/share/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.6.0/gems/logstash-output-elasticsearch-11.9.3-java/lib/logstash/outputs/elasticsearch/http_client/manticore_adapter.rb:84:in `perform_request'", "/usr/share/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.6.0/gems/logstash-output-elasticsearch-11.9.3-java/lib/logstash/outputs/elasticsearch/http_client/pool.rb:324:in `perform_request_to_url'", "/usr/share/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.6.0/gems/logstash-output-elasticsearch-11.9.3-java/lib/logstash/outputs/elasticsearch/http_client/pool.rb:311:in `block in perform_request'", "/usr/share/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.6.0/gems/logstash-output-elasticsearch-11.9.3-java/lib/logstash/outputs/elasticsearch/http_client/pool.rb:398:in `with_connection'", "/usr/share/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.6.0/gems/logstash-output-elasticsearch-11.9.3-java/lib/logstash/outputs/elasticsearch/http_client/pool.rb:310:in `perform_request'", "/usr/share/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.6.0/gems/logstash-output-elasticsearch-11.9.3-java/lib/logstash/outputs/elasticsearch/http_client/pool.rb:318:in `block in Pool'", "/usr/share/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.6.0/gems/logstash-output-elasticsearch-11.9.3-java/lib/logstash/outputs/elasticsearch/http_client.rb:412:in `template_put'", "/usr/share/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.6.0/gems/logstash-output-elasticsearch-11.9.3-java/lib/logstash/outputs/elasticsearch/http_client.rb:85:in `template_install'", "/usr/share/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.6.0/gems/logstash-output-elasticsearch-11.9.3-java/lib/logstash/outputs/elasticsearch/template_manager.rb:29:in `install'", "/usr/share/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.6.0/gems/logstash-output-elasticsearch-11.9.3-java/lib/logstash/outputs/elasticsearch/template_manager.rb:17:in `install_template'", "/usr/share/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.6.0/gems/logstash-output-elasticsearch-11.9.3-java/lib/logstash/outputs/elasticsearch.rb:578:in `install_template'", "/usr/share/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.6.0/gems/logstash-output-elasticsearch-11.9.3-java/lib/logstash/outputs/elasticsearch.rb:344:in `finish_register'", "/usr/share/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.6.0/gems/logstash-output-elasticsearch-11.9.3-java/lib/logstash/outputs/elasticsearch.rb:300:in `block in register'", "/usr/share/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.6.0/gems/logstash-output-elasticsearch-11.9.3-java/lib/logstash/plugin_mixins/elasticsearch/common.rb:154:in `block in after_successful_connection'"]}
```

I think i got an error inside my index template but even on internet i didn't found what is wrong with it.

I am using:
logstash:8.5.3
elastictsearch:8.5.3
kibana:8.5.3

this is my template:

```json
{
  "template": "twitter-*",
  "settings": {
    "number_of_shards": 1,
    "number_of_replicas": 0,
    "index.mapping.total_fields.limit": 2000
  },
  "mappings": {
    "_default_": {
      "_all": {
        "enabled": true
      },
      "properties": {
        "@timestamp": {
          "type": "date",
          "format": "dateOptionalTime"
        },
        "created_at": {
          "type": "date",
          "format": "EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss Z YYYY"
        },
        "text": {
          "type": "text"
        },
        "user": {
          "type": "object",
          "properties": {
            "description": {
              "type": "text"
            }
          }
        },
        "coordinates": {
          "type": "object",
          "properties": {
            "coordinates": {
              "type": "geo_point"
            }
          }
        },
        "entities": {
          "type": "object",
          "properties": {
            "hashtags": {
              "type": "object",
              "properties": {
                "text": {
                  "type": "text",
                  "fielddata": true
                }
              }
            }
          }
        },
        "retweeted_status": {
          "type": "object",
          "properties": {
            "text": {
              "type": "text"
            }
          }
        }
      },
      "dynamic_templates": [
        {
          "string_template": {
            "match": "*",
            "match_mapping_type": "string",
            "mapping": {
              "type": "keyword"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

and this is my logstash config, i send my tweet via tcp because i have a python bot who fetch them for me.

```
input {
        tcp {
                port => 50000
        }
}


filter {


}

output {
        elasticsearch {
                hosts => "elasticsearch:9200"
                user => "elastic"
                password => "${LOGSTASH_INTERNAL_PASSWORD}"
                index => "twitter-%{+yyyy.MM.dd}"
                document_type => "tweets"
                template      => "./templates/twitter.json"
                template_name => "twitter"
                template_overwrite => true
        }
}
```

Thanks for any help <3

What did you try ?
I tried to modify some attributes of my template, but i still got this message.

What were you expecting?
I was expecting that logstash create my index_template, for incoming tweets.

Comment: Can you give specifics on some of the values you modified and what the results were?

Comment: @ryanwebjackson Hello i tried to remove the `_default_` attribute because i saw that it worked for a guy on an other forum, but for me unfortunatly i've got the same error message